# Sorting issue with datetime objects using comparator

Tags: java

Hi i have the following datetime objects

E.g. like

```
25/06/2012, 11:45 AM
25/06/2012, 12:00 AM
25/06/2012, 12:15 AM
```

I expecting the sorting order to be exactly like above using the comparator class method

But however it return me with a result like below:

Can anyone advise what should be the correct comparable method to be used?

```
25/06/2012, 12:00 AM
25/06/2012, 12:15 AM
25/06/2012, 11:45 AM
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your comparator is already giving the logical result. 12:00 AM is midnight, and comes before 11:45 AM.

Midday is 12:00 PM, which then comes before 1:00 PM.

I would certainly *hope* that's the ordering you want, even though it's not the lexicographic order of this particular representation. (If you use a 24-hour representation instead of 12-hour + am/pm designator, it's a lot clearer.)

Comment: [Confusion at noon and midnight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock#Confusion_at_noon_and_midnight)